# How to store entire commands in bash variables and exec them literally with limited word splitting?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, quoting

I have many lines like the following, where the prefix is always the same and the actual executed commands differ.

```sh
ssh -F "${SSH_CFG}" "${SSH_DST}" "[...]"
ssh -F "${SSH_CFG}" "${SSH_DST}" "[...]"
ssh -F "${SSH_CFG}" "${SSH_DST}" "[...]"
```

To not need to repeat myself, I would like to make the whole prefix be one variable as well, like in the following example:

```sh
SSH_CMD="ssh -F ""${SSH_CFG}"" ""${SSH_DST}"""

${SSH_CMD} "[...]"
${SSH_CMD} "[...]"
${SSH_CMD} "[...]"
```

This works as long as spaces aren't used as part of paths or options, because from my understanding the prefix like used above is subject to word splitting by the shell. Of course I have some options with spaces for various reasons and those options need to be forwarded as-is, as one argument. That is not the case in the above example and the overall command fails. OTOH, quoting the prefix is wrong as well, because in that case one command with its arguments would be considered one file and isn't found. So the following example doesn't work:

```sh
SSH_CMD="ssh -F ""${SSH_CFG}"" ""${SSH_DST}"""

"${SSH_CMD}" "[...]"
"${SSH_CMD}" "[...]"
"${SSH_CMD}" "[...]"
```

What I would like to have is a variable like the above `SSH_CMD` containing a pre-quoted string already to take care of spaces etc. and that string is used as-is as the prefix. Though, in that case I would still need some level of word-splitting by the shell using spaces to distinguish the commands and all individual arguments, but within those arguments word-splitting MUST NOT occur to keep paths and options with spaces correct. I can't find a way to do the latter: Whatever I try either doesn't survive word-splitting or characters like `"` or `'` are added to paths and options, most likely as a result of wrong word-splitting as well.

```sh
SSH_CMD="ssh -F ""${SSH_CFG}"" ""${SSH_DST}"""

${SSH_CMD} "[...]"
${SSH_CMD} "[...]"
${SSH_CMD} "[...]"
```

to

```sh
SSH_CMD="ssh -F ""${SSH_CFG}"" ""${SSH_DST}"""

ssh -F "${SSH_CFG}" "${SSH_DST}" "[...]"
ssh -F "${SSH_CFG}" "${SSH_DST}" "[...]"
ssh -F "${SSH_CFG}" "${SSH_DST}" "[...]"
```

**So, is there any way to get something like the example above to work at all?**

Thanks!

Comment: See the "How do I store a command in a variable?" section of <https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function, not a variable.

```
ssh_cmd () {
    ssh -F "$SSH_CFG" "$SSH_DST" "$@"
}


ssh_cmd "[...]"
ssh_cmd "[...]"
ssh_cmd "[...]"
```

The body of the function needs no additional quoting beyond what you would use ordinarily, and `"$@"` ensures that your arguments to `ssh_cmd` are preserved as distinct arguments in the call to `ssh`.